# System namespace overlaps with MyApp.System namespace in Desginer.cs - CS0234 error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my Windows Forms project `System` namespace is overlaps with `MyApp.System` namespace.

I get `CS0234 error: "The type or namespace name "Windows" does not exist in the namespace "MyApp.System" (are you missing an assembly reference?)"` in "MyWindow.Designer.cs".

Yes, I know that I could change `System.Windows` to `global::System.Windows` and it will work for a while, but when my window UI is touched `MyWindow.Designer.cs` is regenerated and problem returns.

Comment: My suggestion would be to rename your namespace to avoid the collision.

Comment: I'm considering this option, but maybe there is some other solution?

Comment: Any alternative is going to still have more friction that if you just avoid using System, IMO.